# jQuery event and animation

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-animate, jquery-events

I have made quick sliding content holder, using absolute positioning, and one the click of a link, new content slides in based on the links that was clicked so far example if I click '3' then the `#section3` slides into view and the previous content slides out of view.  However if then I want to bring that content back into I cannot do so, how can I work around this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Udders/Wj2aS/

Above is a fiddle of what I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Wj2aS/3/

```
$('a.next').click(function() {
    var anchor = $(this).attr('href');
    $(anchor).animate({
        "left": "0px"
    }, 1000).addClass('current')

        .prev('div').animate({
        "left": "-1000px"
    }, 1000).removeClass('current')

        .end().next('div').animate({
        "left": "+1000px"
    }, 1000).removeClass('current');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your fiddle with added "prev" link for second section:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wj2aS/5/